# Create collection of JSONObjects from list of Kotlin objects

Tags: json, kotlin, android-room

I have a room database from which I can get a `List<LearningEvent>`, which I then have to convert into a `Collection<JSONObject>` and return it. How can I efficiently do that?

Here's the `LearningEvent` class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "learningEvents")
data class LearningEvent(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "learningeventid")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null,
    var sessionId: Long,
    var time: Float,
    var eventType: String,
    var description: String,
    var feedback: String
)
```

Here's the DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM learningEvents WHERE sessionId = :sessionId")
suspend fun getAllLearningEvents(sessionId: Long?): List<LearningEvent>
```

And here's my non-working/non-building code for the getEvents() function:

```
 override suspend fun getEvents(): Collection<JSONObject> =
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Log.d("\ngetEvents(eventType)", currentSessionId.toString())
            if (currentSessionId === null) {
                throw Exception("Current session Id is null; Session cannot be retrieved.")
            }

            var gson = Gson();

            // Return JSON object collection of table rows.
            var learningEvents = db.learningEventDao().getAllLearningEvents(currentSessionId);
            var returnCollection = emptyList<JSONObject>();
            learningEvents.forEach{element ->
                var singleObject = gson.toJsonTree(element);
                returnCollection += singleObject;
            }

            return@withContext returnCollection;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion, you can convert LearningEvent to JSONObject using `.toJson`. Here the sample code:

```
var learningEvents = db.learningEventDao().getAllLearningEvents(currentSessionId);
var returnCollection = emptyList<JSONObject>();
learningEvents.forEach{ element ->
      val singleObject = gson.toJson(element);
      returnCollection += JSONObject(singleObject);
}
```

Comment: In the end, I used `JSONObject(mapOf("session" to element.sessionId, ...`. Thank you for your input.